# insert statement is not working while in lan

Tags: sql-server

I am working with SQL server in LAN, I have a problem while inserting into one of the table from other computer in LAN. My SQL-server is available in LAN and able to retrieve details from other computers. While inserting data from another computer it says data added, but when I try to see the data that was added, the query is taking infinite time (Not showing any results). I'd have to restart the server.

SQL server, windows 10. I have tried adding with a different user from my laptop to see if it's user problem, but it is working.

The data should be inserted from any other computer in LAN.

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem with LAN? Try running `sp_who` and `sp_who2` from another window of SSMS while running your `SELECT` to see what is blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer I forgot to commit, the transaction. it works fine now after commit.
Thanks.